# XMPP chatting not working between Android and iOS devices?

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, smack, xmppframework

I am developing an XMPP chat application on both Android and iOS.

Chatting is working fine between iPhone simulator and iOS device.
It's also working between Android emulator and Android device.
However, it is not working between android device and iOS device.

Can any one please suggest to me what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance..

Update:

Messages are coming from Android device to iOS device, but not from iOS to android.

I used this for Android:

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(testHost,portNumber);
connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
```

I used this for iOS:

```
XMPPJID *jid=[XMPPJID jidWithString:loginDetails.username];

password=loginDetails.password; 

[[self xmppStream] setMyJID:jid];
NSError *error;
if (![[self xmppStream] connect:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
    return NO;
}
return YES;

if (allowSelfSignedCertificates)
{
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];
}

if (allowSSLHostNameMismatch)
{
    [settings setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
}

else
{
    // Google does things incorrectly (does not conform to RFC).
    // Because so many people ask questions about this (assume xmpp framework is broken),
    // I've explicitly added code that shows how other xmpp clients "do the right thing"
    // when connecting to a google server (gmail, or google apps for domains).

    NSString *expectedCertName = nil;

    NSString *serverHostName = [sender hostName];
    NSString *virtualHostName = [[sender myJID] domain];

    if ([serverHostName isEqualToString:@"talk.google.com"])
    {
        if ([virtualHostName isEqualToString:@"gmail.com"])
            expectedCertName = virtualHostName;
        else 
            expectedCertName = serverHostName;
    }
    else
    {
        expectedCertName = serverHostName;
    }

    [settings setObject:expectedCertName forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
}
```

Comment: You should give some more details. I guess the problem lays in the sending/recieving process, which isn't the same on your Android/iPhone Device. This is why it works from Android to Android and from iPhone to iPhone.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth  it even worked from android--jwchat and jwchat--iphone .  alloeSelfSignedCertificates is set to YES in both iphone and android

Comment: We need some code to provide answers. If this is the source of the problem...

Comment: i have added code, please check once